# Logitech MX Anywhere 2S extra buttons configuration

Tags: mouse, logitech

I am in the process of switching from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. I am a complete novice when it comes to Linux/Ubuntu. I tried searching how to allocate the extra mouse buttons to the desired functions, but all questions and answers appear to relate to older versions of Ubuntu. Logitech does not offer a Linux version of their support software. How can I configure the function of my mouse buttons?

Comment: I have now successfully assigned the "back" and "forward" function to my scroll wheel left and right movement by installing xbindkey and editing .xbindkeysrc with the lines:

# Back
"xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'key Left' 'keyup Alt_L'"
  b:6

# Forward
"xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'key Right' 'keyup Alt_L'"
  b:7

However, I would also like to assign the thumb buttons to be "ctrl" and "shift" so that when I press 1 thumb button and then click on a link or file, it has the same effects as holding down the CTRL or Shift key while clicking. I can not seem to find a working command line for that.

Comment: I tried making the command line:

# CTRL
"xte 'keydown Ctrl_L' 'keyup Ctrl_L'"
  b:8

And also

# CTRL
"xte 'keydown Ctrl_L'"
  b:8

But neither work. Any help on how to get this working would be very welcome.